# Why prometheus configmap is failing to reload the configmaps?

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, kube-prometheus-stack

I'm using kube-prometheus-stack https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack helm chart to monitor my k8s cluster. So i have configured alertmanager to send alerts to slack. This part is working well. In configmap `prometheus-prome-stack-dev-kube-prome-prometheus-rulefiles-0` I'm editing some rules.
But somehow k8s is not able to pick up the updated configmaps. Since prometheus pod comes with  built in config reloader.
But still not unable to pick up the configmaps.
Even I tried sending POST request
***curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/-/reload***
I dint get any response. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanksin advance.

```
config-reloader:
    Container ID:  docker://b2c7efda9e7e9a308113d07e5482b1df00d144fb9b764fcc2ba608feeb82ee0e
    Image: quay.io/prometheus-operator/prometheus-config-reloader:v0.49.0
```

Comment: Did you check if the reload is failing due to invalid configuration? What does it say in the Prometheus UI under _Status > Runtime & Build Information > Configuration reload_?

Comment: Configuration reload: Successful@weibeld

Comment: And the time coincides with the time you do `curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/-/reload`?

Comment: did you get what was the issue cause here ? facing same @AkshayAwate